# Icecast seems play stream multiple instance

Tags: caching, stream, icecast

I set up an icecast server with ices0 source client. 
Everything works fine but sometimes it seems as if play multiple instance from the stream. For example when a track gets its end and I refresh the stream I hear some seconds again from the end of the last track not the beggining from the new one.

Can you help me what happens?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to an Icecast served stream, Icecast usually sends a "burst" of data to reduce the time a client has to buffer before playing something. Depending on the burst-size, you can end up getting a bit of the "old" data. This is completely normal. You can disable the burst but that's not really advisable in general as it will cause longer buffering times. Depending which clients you serve though, this might not be a concern in your use-case.

Another note: Icecast is not intended for low-latency streaming, so if this is what you are looking for, this is not something Icecast can do.